# Is there any function to merge two JSON data-sets with replacing old information? (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Every object in JSON have unique ID. Is there any build-in function that merging two JSON's with updating information by id?

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "users": [
        { 
             "id": "test1",
             "field1": "info1",
             "field2": "info1"
        },
        { 
             "id": "test2",
             "field": "info1"
        },
        { 
             "id": "test3",
             "field": "info1"
        }
}
```

If this function doesn't exist - i will write my own. I'm asking this because my function will definitely work slower.

Comment: you can merge them with O(n+m).

Comment: You can use `_` for that. First require it `var _ = require('lodash'); ` and then use it like `var updatedObj = _.merge(obj1, obj2);`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera i get exception on `_`

Comment: You will first have to do an `npm install lodash`

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera just 1 question. How it will know that object `{"id": "test1", "field": "info1"}` is the same as `{"id": "test1", "field": "info1222"}` and have to be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lodash's `merge` method](https://lodash.com/docs#merge).

Firstly do `npm install lodash`

Then require lodash in your module using `var _ = require('lodash');`

Then you'll be able to merge two JSON Objects. Here's an example

```
var users = {
    'data': [{ 'user': 'barney' }, { 'user': 'fred' }]
};

var ages = {
    'data': [{ 'age': 36 }, { 'age': 40 }]
};

_.merge(users, ages);
// → { 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
```

In your case :

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var obj1 = {"id": "test1", "field": "info1"};
var obj2 = {"id": "test1", "field": "info1222"};
var mergedObj = _.merge(obj1, obj2);
```

The value of `mergedObj` would be `{"id": "test1", "field": "info1222"}` as it would replace the value of the `field` which was `info1` with `info1222`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sorry, but you got me wrong. By "id" i didn't mean the sequence of the object. In my example "id" is a field.

Comment: I got what you meant. `_.merge` simply takes two objects and merges them together. It replaces the field values from the first object by the field values of the second object. And it doesn't change the fields and values that are same in both the objects. It adds new field value pairs if they are present in the second object and are not present in the first object.

Comment: So for `var obj1 = {"id": "test1", "field": "info1"} ` and var obj2 =  {"id": "test1", "field": "info1222"}` `var mergedObj = _.merge(obj1, obj2)` would yield `mergedObj` to be `{"id": "test1", "field": "info1222"}`

Comment: There is only 1 problem. Second array may not contain all ids (that does not mean that this information must be removed). No one guarantee that objects are sorted. Second array may contain new id's.

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in function that would help you in your case. There should be at-least one field that uniquely identifies each JSON object in both the arrays.